# How do I write a string to the Slime REPL's input buffer?

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

I'm writting a shell in Common Lisp that reads command from the user's input and returns the output after executing. When the user types a "meta" command I want to write a placeholder so that the user can either press enter and send that command to the shell, or edit this command as if it were their own input.

This what I have now:

```lisp
(defun eval-print (command-executor command)
  (format t "~a~%" (funcall command-executor command)))

(defun cmd-exec-local (command)
  "Execute a command in the local shell"
  (trim (uiop:run-program command :output :string)))

(defun shell (command-executor &optional placeholder)
  "Simulate a REPL"
  (progn
    (if placeholder
        (format t ">>> ~a" placeholder) ; This is were I try to show a placeholder
        (format t ">>> "))
    (let ((command (read-line))) ; Check if the user wrote a meta command, else just execute whatever they wrote
      (cond ((string= "@exit" command) (format t "Bye!~%")) ; Exit the shell
            ((string= "@bashrev" command) (shell command-executor *bash-rev*)) ; Bash reverse shell
            ((string= "@info" command) (shell command-executor "whoami")) ; System info
            (t (eval-print command-executor command) (shell command-executor)))))) ; Execute the command
```

But this is the output I get:

```lisp
PENTESTING> (shell #'cmd-exec-local)
>>> @info
>>> whoami ; This has been written to the standard output, so even if I press enter, nothing gets executed

>>> whoami ; This was written by the user so when pressing enter, I get the results I need
kali
>>> @exit
Bye!
```

My guess is I need some kind of buffer that I can write to but I've tried *terminal-io* and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I reproduce… note that a real line-handling library like readline would make it possible (but then outside of the editor).

Comment: style: you don't need a `progn` inside the `defun`.

Comment: What are the definitions of your ```eval-print``` and ```trim``` functions ?

Comment: @JérômeRadix I added `eval-print`'s definition to the OP, `trim` is imported from the library `str`.

Comment: This is indeed a great question, the use of ```*query-io*``` does not allow such kind of thing you want. And clearly your ```(format t ">>> ~a"  placeholder)``` doesn't do the trick. I just don't see how it all relates to SLIME. You'd better remove all references to Slime in your question (and remove the slime tag)

Comment: I think you may find a solution using https://github.com/sharplispers/linedit.git but it's not well documented.

Comment: For a Lisp shell I would use cl-charms (ncurses) to manipulate the terminal (a bit like utop for ocaml). This tutorial is quite good http://turtleware.eu/posts/cl-charms-crash-course.html and I remember I managed to change the input gadget to show a placeholder whenever the buffer is empty.